# Laravel dusk assert flash message

Tags: laravel, testing, browser-testing

I have following flash message generated on my page

```
flash('Success message')->success();
```

Trying to assert through

```
->assertSee('Success message');
```

With no luck

```
<div class="alert
                    alert-success
                    " role="alert">              
            Success message
        </div>
```

I will always get

```
Did not see expected text [Success message] within element [body].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Despite the fact the message is in the body

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using alert

Use:`$browser->assertDialogOpened('Success message');`